# StackOverflowError after upgrading to RestEasy 4.5.x

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, resteasy, jetty-9

After upgrading to RestEasy from 4.4.2 to 4.5.2, I got a `StackOverflowError` when returning a response with an entity InputStream.
Returning a basic 10MB stream fails.

Bug reproductible with very basic code:

```
@Path("/")
public class TestResource {

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM)
    @Path("/{size}")
    public Response donwload(@PathParam("size") long size) {
        return Response.ok(new NullInputStream(size)).build();
    }
}
```

Requesting :

```
localhost:8000/1000000  ==> OK
localhost:8000/10000000 ==> StackOverflowError
```

I get :

```
org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannelOverHttp.handleException(HttpChannelOverHttp.java:488) :  java.lang.StackOverflowError: null
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.BufferUtil.fill(BufferUtil.java:503)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpOutput.write(HttpOutput.java:791)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletResponseWrapper$DeferredOutputStream.write(HttpServletResponseWrapper.java:153)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletResponseWrapper$AsyncOperation.work(HttpServletResponseWrapper.java:41)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletResponseWrapper$DeferredOutputStream.queue(HttpServletResponseWrapper.java:219)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletResponseWrapper$DeferredOutputStream.asyncWrite(HttpServletResponseWrapper.java:180)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.util.CommitHeaderAsyncOutputStream.asyncWrite(CommitHeaderAsyncOutputStream.java:94)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.providers.ProviderHelper.writeTo(ProviderHelper.java:171)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.providers.ProviderHelper.lambda$writeTo$1(ProviderHelper.java:172)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniComposeStage(CompletableFuture.java:1106)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.thenCompose(CompletableFuture.java:2235)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.thenCompose(CompletableFuture.java:143)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.providers.ProviderHelper.writeTo(ProviderHelper.java:172)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.providers.ProviderHelper.lambda$writeTo$1(ProviderHelper.java:172)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniComposeStage(CompletableFuture.java:1106)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.thenCompose(CompletableFuture.java:2235)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.thenCompose(CompletableFuture.java:143)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.providers.ProviderHelper.writeTo(ProviderHelper.java:172)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.providers.ProviderHelper.lambda$writeTo$1(ProviderHelper.java:172)
        ...
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniComposeStage(CompletableFuture.java:1106)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.thenCompose(CompletableFuture.java:2235)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.thenCompose(CompletableFuture.java:143)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.providers.ProviderHelper.writeTo(ProviderHelper.java:172)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.providers.ProviderHelper.lambda$writeTo$1(ProviderHelper.java:172)
        ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I reported the bug https://issues.redhat.com/browse/RESTEASY-2526 and it's been resolved since

Answer (score -1):

After debug your problem, I think the there is no problem in restEasy. The root cause is default JVM configure do not allocate enough memory for the stack. If you setup the JVM stack frame size greater than 10M by yourself, the error would not occur.

Below is my configure in my Idea. I setup 16M for stack frame.

[image]

The code works fine and 10M can be download

[image]

Comment: How about a 1TB file? shoud I define 1GB stack frame?

Comment: @Lotfi According to the code，the write operation is done in inputstream and outputstream.  You say that this code works fine in 4.4.2？ Right? If so, I think i shoukd i read the code in revision 4.4.2